iOS real device not connecting to metro server so that can't able to see logs
when I am running my react-native application on real iOS device it build successfully, installed and running correctly but without metro bundler, so I am not able to get the logs and reload application
I am on the same wifi network
first I run npm start and then run my application still did not worked,
tried to run with x code
the problem that I am facing is: there is no any error but I am not able to see the logs so that I can work and implement new features

Are you resolved? please help me, same issue!
